# WireMock returning 404 when using PostJsonAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, wiremock

Getting a weird issue when using WireMock. This is my setup:

```
var reAuthRequest = new ReAuthRequest
{
  ResponseType = "code"
};

var serializeObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(reAuthRequest);

_authServer
.Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/v1/reauthuri").WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").UsingPost().WithBody(serializeObject))
.RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```

For some reason when I do this I get a 404 response back

```
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/v1/reauthuri", authRequest);
```

However when I do this I get the correct 200 response.

```
var str = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(reAuthRequest);
var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/v1/reauthuri", new StringContent(str));
```

PostJsonAsync is setting up some additional headers that I need WireMock to also have but not sure what. Any ideas what this could be?

Model being serialized is this:

```
public class ReAuthRequest
{
    public string? ResponseType { get; set; }
}
```

I updated it to use

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClientJsonExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync` uses System.Text.Json for the serialization of the provided object.

I assume the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method you are using is from Newtonsoft.Json.

Note that the behavior of System.Text.Json is not perfectly identical with Newtonsoft.Json ([see here for a comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson)). And i suspect that the json generated from the object referred to by *authRequest* differs between System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.

Now, what precisely the difference is in your situation and what could be done to resolve the issue, i don't know, as we have no information about the type of the object that is referred to by the variable *authRequest*. (It could be that the type in questions possesses public fields instead of properties, which System.Text.Json does not serialize by default, whereas Newtonsoft.Json does. But it could also be any number of other things instead where the differences between the behaviors of System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json could potentially matter here...)

If the issue is not with differences in the generated json payload, observe and compare the request headers transmitted using `_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` vs. `_httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` with *StringContent*. A tool like [Telerik's Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) comes in handy for inspecting web requests (and responses).